# Using json field in jpa entity (implementing hibernate UserType)

Tags: java, hibernate

I hope you will help me..
I have an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id; 

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Type(type = "JsonDataUserType")
    @Column
    private Map<String, Object> additionalData;
    //.....
    // some data
}
```

JsonDataUserType implements UserType interface (hibernate) and is placed in db as json format (json object with key-value entries)

I don't know what fields will be placed in additionalData json field (keys are defined by the user)..
I save in db, for example...

```
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.getAdditionalData().put("age", 15);
person1.getAdditionalData().put("gender", "male");
person1.getAdditionalData().put("position", "something");
// .. save to db

Person person2 = new Person();
person2.getAdditionalData().put("height", 180);
person2.getAdditionalData().put("nick name", "hahaha");
person2.getAdditionalData().put("slogan", "I'm not stupid");
// .. save to db
```

And after I want to make a query like:

```
select p from Person p where p.additionalData.slogan = :slogan...
```

How can I make similar query? 
Hibernate's documentation says that i shoud implement CompositeUserType in order to use custom user type in criteria jpql/hql, but I also have to implement getPropertyNames() and getPropertyTypes().. but in runtime I don't know anything about field names (keys) in additionalData..
I hope someone can help me or suggests another solution..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
@Query("select p from Person p where p.additionalData->>':key' = :value")
List<Person> findByKeyValue(@Param("key") String key, @Param("value") Object value) {
}
```

You can call it now as `repository.findByKeyValue("height", 180)` or `repository.findByKeyValue("slogan", "I'm not stupid")`